# how to solve The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular6

i am facing this error please help me this when i publish my app in IIS with angularjs please help me  how to solve this error iam using .net core 2.1 and angularjs . In visual studio working fine I am facing this error in IIS

```
  services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
            });


app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

Error Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Angular 1.x? Or angular 2 and above?

Comment: angular6........

Comment: can you try compiling in visual studio code and view output?

Comment: Have you managed to come up with a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 11):

- npm script 'start' means, .Net Core is trying to call `ng serve` to
  run the angular module in development env. So when your are hosting
  your application in Azure/local or any other server, make sure you
  have not deployed your application in Development environment.
  `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"` Change it to
  `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"`. [Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
- After you have deployed in production mode and still facing any other
  errors. Try the following to find out the error. Comment out the
  following code block in Startup.cs

> //if (env.IsDevelopment())
>       // {
>       //    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
>       // }

and deploy the application back in Development mode. You will get the real error message.

The variable can be changed in the ServiceManifest.xml file. By default it is not set.

Comment: How do you "deploy in production mode"?

Comment: In my case I had web.config file that was getting updated with an ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable during the publish process.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseSpaStaticFiles();    

      app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
              routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

              routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });

      app.UseSpa(spa =>
      {
        // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
        // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
          spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
      });

    }
```

[image: Add index.cshtml]

Answer (score 1):

Note the pertinent part of the error `**npm** is not recognized as an inernal or external command`.

I was getting this error on a fresh Windows and VS install. Turns out that despite choosing the node.js development tools in the VS installer, node wasn't actually installed, so neither was npm.

You can test this by running `node -v` as the command prompt.

Solved for me by installing node. Note you may also have to do an `npm install` to download the dependencies in `node_modules` if you don't have them.

Answer (score 0):

I installed node.js and ready, I solved the problem. So please install node.js and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Select the node modules present Folder open on CMD Window

> npm start

*** Any error occurs like software installation Failed.
Give this command

> npm install

*** After completion of npm install without error

> npm start.

Get the IP from output and change the local host number in asp.net project.Then  run the project it works.